# How to export Jupyter Notebook to html with line numbers in code cells

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have been searching unsuccessfully for information on how to export jupyter notebooks to html with code lines numbered.

Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved [in this issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5847) of the ipython GitHub repository.

Basically nbconvert hasn't got a setting for this, but you can create a custom template to get the result you need.